# Variable view in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Don't know if this question belongs here; my apologies if it doesn't. I am looking for a way to have a "Variable view" in R akin to SPSS's variable view. I want to see a list of variables in some dataframe along with their labels (if they exist) and the type of the variable (numeric, character...)

Of course, it's possible to see all these parameters by using code, but it feels very tiresome to constantly type `colnames(data)` into the console, or to constantly use `data %>% map(class)` to see the class of each variable.

I am looking for an add-on or something like that which would make all this info available with one mouse click.

Edit: Let's say I have this code:

```
data %>%
map(class) %>%
data.frame() %>%
t() %>%
View()
```

I just want a simple button next to the object in the environment that would automatically call this code on an object when I click on the button.

Comment: `str(mydata)` probably

Comment: @jay.sf Thanks but no, I'm specifically looking for something that doesn't need explicit use of code (for example, like a "table" icon next to your data that calls the `View` function but you don't have to type `View(data)` in the console yourself. Also, the output needs to be a table and not a mess that you get when calling `str(data)`

Answer (score 3):

The `RStudio` I'm using is `Version 1.2.5019`. In the upper right pane there is an `Environment/History` window which has a play button for each dataframe in the left side. If you click the play button,  it expands to show you the `typeof` of the variables in the dataframe as well as a value from the variables. Here is a screen shot from my `RStudio`

[image: RStuidio_var-view]

As you can see above, it is from the `Environment` tab of `Environment/History` window, and I've expanded `cars.df` `datframe` for you to see what it does. It shows that there are two variables in the dataframe, namely `speed` and `dist` which are of type `numerical`.

Hope that is the feature you want.

Comment: This is maybe best of all the current answers, but as far as I see, this button calls `str(data)` - when I click it, I can see `.. -attr(*, "format.spss") = chr A255"` and in the next row `.. -attr(*, "display_width") = int 0` and only below I can see the name and the type of the variable. Furthermore, the button is not visible when the Grid view is selected (upper-right corner of the Environment pane). I understand that I'm looking for something highly specific, but I was hoping that maybe there is a commonly used plugin or something.

Answer (score 1):

The Tab *Environment* (per se upper right corner of RStudio) might be what you are looking for. It shows data frames and values; for data frames there is an icon left ot the name to show all columns.

Comment: Sorry this is actually the same answer as @deepseafan I just misread it the first time and you posted it earlier. Very close, but still not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the button you're looking for ;-)

If you put the objectname inbetween the brackets (in my example the object cars) and hand it over to the view function of R inside RStudio:

```
View(cars)
```

You can see the result in a new tab:
[Call Rs view function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpRVF.png)